# How to convert a sparse matrix to a dense matrix from .mat file in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, sparse-file

```
import xlrd, xlwt
import scipy as sp
import scipy.io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
%matplotlib inline

FileString = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Thesis/EXIOBASE_3rx_aggLandUseExtensions_2015_pxp.mat'
MRIO = scipy.io.loadmat(FileString)

Regions = MRIO['IO']['A']

IN: Regions
OUT: array([[<42800x42800 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5986549 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>]],
      dtype=object)

IN: Regions.todense()
OUT: 
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-3ef413dd7ae9> in <module>()
----> 1 Regions.todense()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'todense'
```

**I am trying to convert this sparse matrix from a MATLAB file into a dense matrix, thus I applied todense() function but I don't know why it doesn't work. Your help will be highly appreciated
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpack:

```
array([[<42800x42800 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 5986549 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>]],
  dtype=object)
```

This is a `ndarray` as shown by the error.  It has shape (1,1), `object` dtype.  That one object is the sparse matrix.  I deduced that from the display, the `array`, `object` and [[...]]`.

```
x[0,0].todense()
x[0,0].A        # for array
```

should work.

I'd suggest first displaying

```
 x[0,0]
```

I suspect in MATLAB this is a `cell`, with size (1,1).  `loadmat` makes a liberal use of `object` dtype arrays to hold MATLAB `cell` and `struct`.  Only a pure matrix becomes a numeric array.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your advice, In MATLAB it's a "42800x42800 sparse double"